# How to build and deploy kubernetes cluster to Google Cloud using Cloud Build and Skaffold?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, skaffold

I am new to micro-services technologies and getting troubled with Google Cloud Build.
I am using Docker, Kubernetes, Ingres Nginx and skaffold and my deployment works fine in local machine.

Now I want to develop locally and build and run remotely using Cloud Platform so, here's what I have done:

- In Google Cloud, I have set up *kubernetes cluster*
- Set local kubectl context to cloud cluster
- Set up an *Ingress Nginx* load balancer
- Enabled Cloud Build API (no trigger setup)

Here's my *create deployment* and *skaffold* yaml files look like:
[image]

When I run **skaffold dev**, it logs out: *Some taggers failed. Rerun with -vdebug for errors.*, then it takes some time and my network bandwidth.

The image does get pushed to **Cloud Container Registry** and I can access the app using load balancer's IP address but the **Cloud Build History** is still empty. Where am I missing?

**Note:** Right now I am not pushing my code to any online repository like github.

Sorry If the information I provide is insufficient, I am new to these technologies.

Comment: Can you share your cloud build configuration file?

Comment: There is no cloudbuild.yaml, in my skaffold.yaml file -> line no. 10-11 is telling skaffold to use google cloud build.

Comment: Did you have check the Cloud Build logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Build started working:

First, In Cloud Build settings, I enabled kubernetes Engine, Compute Engine and Service Accounts.

Then, I executed these 2 commands:

1. `gcloud auth application-default login`:  As google describes it *This will acquire new user credentials to use for Application Default Credentials*
2. As mentioned in *ingress nginx -> deploy -> GCE-GKE* documentation, *this will Initialize your user as a cluster-admin*

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding \
  --clusterrole cluster-admin \
  --user $(gcloud config get-value account)
```